# Python ctype: char array to c function is not getting updated when the c function writes values to it

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-3.7, ctypes

Here is my C code:

```
//int MyFunc(char* res); -> This is the definition of C function
char data[4096];  
MyFunc(data);
printf("Data is : %s\n", data);
```

The `data` variable is updated by the C function. I used `bytearray` in Python to pass the variable as argument but the updated array is not reflecting. Any working code sample is much appreciated.

EDIT: I am using Python 3.7.
My Python code:

```
data = bytearray(b'1234567890')
str_buffer = create_string_buffer(bytes(data), len(data))
print(MyFunc(str_buffer))
print(str_buffer.value) #Output: b''
```

`str_buffer` does not contain the values updated by `MyFunc()`.
Calling `MyFunc()` from C# using the below signature works for me. I am looking for a Python 3.7 equivalent of it.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int MyFunc(StringBuilder data);
```

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: I updated my question. My apologies for not adding the python sample previously.

Comment: Do you realize that you're printing the `int` that your function is returning, not the new value of `str_buffer`? How do you know it doesn't contain the updated values if your code never uses it after you update them?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: I missed to add  the print statement that prints `str_buffer.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bytearray` isn't the right way to pass a `char *` to a C function. Use `create_string_buffer` instead. Also, `len(data)` is an off-by-one error that results in a null terminator not being present, so either stick a `+ 1` on that or remove it, as the default length is right. Here's a minimal working example. First, a C function that turns every letter uppercase, and returns the number of letters that were already uppercase:

```c
#include <ctype.h>

int MyFunc(char* res) {
    int i = 0;
    while(*res) {
        if(isupper(*res)) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            *res = toupper(*res);
        }
        ++res;
    }
    return i;
}
```

I compiled it with `gcc -fPIC -shared upstring.c -o upstring.so`. Since you're on Windows, you'll have to adapt this.

Now, some Python that calls it:

```py
from ctypes import *
upstring = CDLL("./upstring.so") # Since you're on Windows, you'll have to adapt this too.
data = bytearray(b'abc12DEFGHI')
str_buffer = create_string_buffer(bytes(data)) # Note: using len(data) would be an off-by-one error that would lose the null terminator, so either omit it or use len(data)+1
print(upstring.MyFunc(str_buffer)) # prints 6
print(str_buffer.value) # prints b'ABC12DEFGHI'
```

Comment: I tried that  already but it did not work for me. Could you provide me a verified example?

Comment: @KannanD Just added one. (And I noticed another problem in your code too.)

Comment: I am following the exact steps as in your code sample and my code has no improvement still. I am running my Python script on Windows. Initially I had a similar problem when using the same C dll in C#. After marking the Characterset of the C function in C# as Ansi, the variable got updated value. Does it give any clue?

Comment: @KannanD Can you post the C code you made your DLL from?

Comment: I tried to create a C dll with your code in it. It works perfectly fine. The C dll which I am using belongs a third-party. So, I will check with that third-party. Thanks for your help.